# can't start script/console with Ruby 1.9 and Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9, irb

I'm trying to start the console (irb) in Ruby 1.9 with Rails 2.3.4. I have two versions installed of Ruby (1.9 & 1.8.6) and I run the Ruby 1.9 by calling: rake19, ruby19, gem19...etc

And they work fine in all situations except this! it seems that its trying to load Ruby 1.8 instead! Do you know how I can change that?

```
Macintosh-10:favquote tammam56$ ruby19 script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
/Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:1
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:1
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:10
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/boot.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/boot.rb:45:in `load_initializer'
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/boot.rb:110
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/environment.rb:8:in `require'
    from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/favquote/config/environment.rb:8
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:252:in `require'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:252:in `load_modules'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:250:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:250:in `load_modules'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/init.rb:21:in `setup'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:54:in `start'
    from /opt/local/bin/irb:13
```

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because script/console is calling irb (1.8). Assuming you have irb19 for ruby 1.9 you could do:

```
script/console --irb='irb19'
```

However there may still be problems with rails gems. If so, I'd recommend using [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your different rubys. When using rvm you will need to install gems separately for ruby 1.9 and 1.8.